# implement one abstract method in two child classes

Tags: c#, abstract

I have two child classes and one parent class.

Parent class have abstract method and it has a class as a parameter. Child class implement the abstract method of parent and it has a another class as a parameter. But the child class method gives an error:

> "does not implement inherited abstract member".

Here is the code:

```
abstract class StudentBizz
{
    public abstract Boolean enrollNewStudent(Student stuObj);
}

class MScStudentBizz:StudentBizz
{
    public override Boolean enrollNewStudent(MScStudent stuObj)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone does `StudentBizz foo = new MScStudentBizz(); foo.enrollNewStudent(new OtherStudent())`? (  `OtherStudent` is a class that inherits from `Student` but not from `MScStudent`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the rest of your code, another approach could be to use [generics with type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) (here I'm assuming `MScStudent` inherits from `Student`):

```
abstract class StudentBizz<TStudent> where TStudent : Student
{
    public abstract Boolean enrollNewStudent(TStudent stuObj);
}

class MScStudentBizz:StudentBizz<MScStudent>
{
    public override Boolean enrollNewStudent(MScStudent stuObj)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the thing that i had expected. It works really well. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The overriding method should have the same signature as the base class method.
So your, overriding method should look like:

```
class MScStudentBizz: StudentBizz 
{ 
  public override Boolean enrollNewStudent(Student student) 
  { 
     //code
  } 
}
```

Comment: if there is no any solution??  only solution is to use same method signature?

Comment: @Nuwan: If you want to change the type of your `student` parameter, you'll need to use a generic type parameter in `StudentBizz`.

Comment: Yes. Declaring an abstract member means you need to have the exact same signature to override. There are two ways to work around it: the best is, as others have suggested, making the base generic on the student type. Another would be to use an interface for the Student method, using an explicit implementation in the derived class that calls through to the more specific overload; that way, code using the interface uses basic students (or even IStudent), while code specifically using the derived class uses the corresponding specialised student.